# jQuery: random active tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to have a tab interface that has a different "active" tab every time the page loads. There will be advertiser content in each of the 4 tabs, so this is a way to keep things "fair". I am familiar with the tabs part...just need pointed in the right direction getting different "active" tabs to display on page load.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GREAT! I got it down to 3 lines! Thanks @Bryan Denny and @GeReV!

JS/jQuery Code:

```
    // Count the number of tabs
    var countTabs = $('.tab_randomiza').children().size(); 

    // Find a random number between 0 and the number of tabs (countTabs)
    var randomizeIt = Math.floor(Math.random()*(countTabs));

    // Tell the tabs which one to be active
    $('#randomiza_wrapper').tabs({ selected: randomizeIt });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="titlebar titlebar_secondary">
        <h3>Test Bucket</h3>
    </div><!-- end .titlebar_secondary -->
    <div id="randomiza_wrapper">
        <ul class="tab_header tab_randomiza">
            <li class="randomiza-tab1 ui-tabs-selected"><a href="#one">one</a></li>
            <li class="randomiza-tab2"><a href="#two">two</a></li>
            <li class="randomiza-tab3"><a href="#three">three</a></li>
            <li class="randomiza-tab4"><a href="#four">four</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="one" class="bucket_secondary randomiza_bucket1">
             <ul class="story_list sidebar_story_list">
                <li>
                    Content One
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- end #one -->


        <div id="two" class="bucket_secondary preventFOUC randomiza_bucket2">
            <ul class="story_list sidebar_story_list ">
                <li>
                    Content Two
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end #two -->

        <div id="three" class="bucket_secondary preventFOUC randomiza_bucket3">
            <ul class="story_list sidebar_story_list ">
                <li>
                    Content Three
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end #three -->

        <div id="four" class="bucket_secondary preventFOUC randomiza_bucket4">
            <ul class="story_list sidebar_story_list ">
                <li>
                    Content Four
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end #four -->
    </div>

</div><!-- end #top_jobs -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a javascript random object.

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*3) //0-3
```

Then set the id of each tab to be based off of that random number.  So if the random number generates a 1, then show tab 2 as the active tab.

Comment: Thanks for using my example, you could also have provided your answer as a comment to mine.

Comment: @BerggreenDK Pardon?  We answered at the same time?  I used this as a resource for a quick copy and paste, as it appears you did too: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/randomnum.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Not that familiar with the tabs yet, but you can count items from Javascript and then select one item by random using Javascript's

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*tabCount);
```

and then use the randomnumber as "tab index".

Answer (score 0):

You could let the SERVER which generates the actual content add a "selected default" to the tab in the rendered HTML output.

Comment: this, i think, is out of the scope of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bryan Denny's answer, here is my **almost** final code:

```
// Make sure none of the tabs are active
$('.randomiza-tab1').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected');
$('.randomiza-tab2').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected');
$('.randomiza-tab3').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected');
$('.randomiza-tab4').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected');

// Make sure none of the content is active
$('.randomiza-bucket1').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');
$('.randomiza-bucket2').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');
$('.randomiza-bucket3').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');
$('.randomiza-bucket4').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');   


// Find a random number between 0 and 3
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

// Add and remove the correct style classes based on random number
switch (randomnumber) {
    case 0 :
        $('.randomiza-tab1').removeClass('hidden').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
        $('.randomiza-bucket1').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');            
        break;

    case 1 :
        $('.randomiza-tab2').removeClass('hidden').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
        $('.randomiza-bucket2').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');            
        break;

    case 2 :
        $('.randomiza-tab3').removeClass('hidden').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
        $('.randomiza-bucket3').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');            
        break;

    case 3 :
        $('.randomiza-tab4').removeClass('hidden').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
        $('.randomiza-bucket4').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');            
        break;

    default :
        $('.randomiza-tab1').removeClass('hidden').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
        $('.randomiza-bucket1').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');            
}
```

Comment: @Pafy: if i knew what i was doing, i wouldn't be asking questions here, now would i? thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
with the `selected` option?

Comment: @GeReV: i am using the ui tabs, but i need the "selected" tab to be random, so the advertisers on the different tabs have a "fair" chance of being seen first on page load...hope that makes sense.

Comment: @tomwolber, as Bryan mentioned, get a random number in `var randomnumber`,
and initialize the tabs with `$(...).tabs({ selected: randomnumber })`.

Comment: OH!...i'm going to try that! I'm sorry, understand what Bryan meant.

Comment: @GeReV: Thanks! I got it down to 3 lines from 25! See my last answer.